# How to calculate means for nested groups and count number of observations in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

all (R users),
THANK YOU VERY MUCH in advance. I've a data set that contains students' scores from multiple states. Each state has different schools (10 schools in this example), each school has to be either 'public' or 'private'; and three items' test scores. I need to calculate the mean of each school for each item, and display the type of school, then save the results into excel file to export them.

The expected result of the excel file would include:

1. column of the name of the state,
2. column of the name of the schools (10 schools for each state column),
3. column of the type of the school (to indicate 'public' or 'private'),
4. number of students in each school,
5. mean of item1,
6. mean of item2,  and
7. mean of item3.

```
library(randomNames)

# example to demonstrate the general concept): 
ID = 1:50
states = rep(c("TS", "NE", "AR", "MO", "WA"),times = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10))
schools = randomNames::randomNames(50) ## 5 first last names separated by a space
type = rep(c("private", "public"),times = c(20,30))
item1 = rnorm(50, mean=25, sd=5)
item2 = rnorm(50, mean=30, sd=5)
item3 = rnorm(50, mean=15, sd=5)
df = data.frame(ID, states, schools, type, item1, item2, item3)
```

Then I need to save it into excel file to export each state separately using the following code:

```
# this below code works fine, I'm just adding it to explain the full concept. 

list_data <- split(df, df$states)
Map(openxlsx::write.xlsx, list_data, paste0(names(list_data), '.xlsx'))
```

THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(states, schools, type) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(across(tidyr::starts_with("item"), ~ mean(.)),
                   students = n()) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()

   states schools             type   item1 item2 item3 students
   <chr>  <chr>               <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <int>
 1 AR     al-Hosein, Zubaida  public  23.4  35.1 15.4         1
 2 AR     al-Mohamed, Raadiya public  24.5  30.8 13.5         1
 3 AR     Bluford, Sage       public  29.9  32.4  9.49        1
 4 AR     Covarrubias, Julio  public  19.8  27.8 15.2         1
 5 AR     el-Gad, Naaila      public  27.0  33.5 19.5         1
 6 AR     el-Mansour, Fawzia  public  34.4  25.4 17.9         1
 7 AR     el-Sadri,  Sakeena  public  24.7  30.5 13.9         1
 8 AR     Ewers, Benjamin     public  18.3  33.6 13.5         1
 9 AR     Rivas, Joel         public  16.8  25.1 20.5         1
10 AR     Wilson, Reneisha    public  28.9  28.5 18.5         1
# ... with 40 more rows
```

If you have other column names that start with `item` then you can change the line `across(tidyr::starts_with(....` to `item1 = mean(item1)` and so on.

The count for student assumes that each row within a school and state is a student and that the type does not change for a given school.

Comment: Thank you VERY much, it worked perfect except for that the only small pieces I still need help with are: 1\ the columns have different names, i.e. they do not start with "item", and 2) they have different col numbers (e.g., col3, col8, col19, etc).

Comment: Change `starts_with("item")` to `starts_with("col")`. The numbers don't matter. It will perform the function on any column with a name that starts with "col".

Comment: My apologies, I mean different name, the name of the columns start differently (e.g., item3, midterm, final, quiz, etc).

Comment: Then follow the suggestion I have posted: delete `across(tidyr::starts_with(....), ...)` and replace it with `item3 = mean(item3), midterm = mean(midterm), ...` within the `summarize` function.

Comment: If you know the column location and it's fixed then you can adjust the code as follows: `across(c(5, 6, 7), mean)`

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis after `midterm` that should go after `n()`: `dplyr::summarize(item3 = mean(item3), midterm = mean(midterm), students = n())`

Comment: You do not need to specify `df$state` using `tidyverse` syntax. Just use `dplyr::group_by(states, schools, type) %>%`

Comment: Works perfect, thanks for your help very much.